# What is the remainder of dividing the $P(x)$ polynomial by $x^2+1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, polynomials, modular-arithmetic, contest-math

> If $P(x)= (x+1)^{2015}+(x-1)^{2015}$ , what is the remainder of dividing the $P(x)$ polynomial by $x^2+1$?
>
> A) $-2^{2015}x$
>
> B) $-2^{1008}x$
>
> C) $2^{1008}x$
>
> D) $2^{2008}$
>
> E) $1$

My attepmts:

Problem is equivalent to $$P(x) \mod (x^2+1)=?$$

Let $x=1$, we have $P(1) \mod (1^2+1)=0$ which imply $R(1)=0$. But no answer matches this. Where is the problem? I can not see my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop the modular arithmetic for a second, and take one step back, so that it's easier to see what's going on when you substitute for $x$. We have that
$$
P(x)=Q(x)(x^2+1)+ax+b
$$
for some polynomial $Q$ and real coefficients $a,b$. We are after $ax+b$.

Note that inserting $x=1$ into this doesn't get us closer, as that gives us
$$
2^{2015}=2Q(2)+a+b
$$
and we still don't have a handle on $Q$. The only thing this tells us is that $a+b$ is even.

On the other hand, inserting $x=i$ or $x=-i$ will make $x^2+1=0$, and the whole $Q$ term vanishes, leaving you with two equations you can solve for $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Do you agree with me? $R(1)=0$ ?

Comment: Even if $R(1)=a\cdot{}1+b=0$ you still have to find $a$ and $b$.

Comment: @Elementary No. You have found that $R(1)$ is _even_ and that's about it.

Comment: @diffset My approach doesnt provide the direct answer. I know this. I must to use only the trick.

Comment: Please, can you explain me Why $R(1)=0$ is not correct?

Comment: @Elementary, Too elementary : $$(1)^2+1\ne0$$

Comment: @Elementary Because inserting $x=1$ into $P(x) \bmod x^2+1$ does not give the same result as $P(1)\bmod 2$. Just consider the much simpler case $P(x)=x^2-1$ to see that this really doesn't work. Or look at where I inserted $x=1$ in my answer to see exactly what information it gives you. Modular arithmetic doesn't give you more, it just writes the same thing in a different way.

Comment: $ai+b=(i+1)^{2015}+(i-1)^{2015}$ then I can use De Moivre formula. Now, Am I correct?

Comment: @Elementary Yes. That's the way I would go.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$P(x)=(x^2+1)Q(x)+Ax+B~~~(*)$$
Put $x=i$ in above to get
$$(i+1)^{2015}+(i-1)^{2015}=Ai+B \implies (1+i)^{2015}-(1-i)^{2015}=Ai+B ~~~(1)$$
By putting $x=-i$ we get
$$(-i+1)^{2015}+(-i-1)^{2015}=-Ai+B \implies -[(1+i)^{2015}-(1-i)^{2015}])~~~(2)$$
Adding (1) and (2) get $B=0$. Then from (1)
$$2^{2015/2} 2i \sin(2015 \pi/4)= A i \implies A=2^{2015/2}~~ 2 \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}=2^{(2015-1)/2}\times -2=-2^{1008}$$
So the reequired remainder from $(*)$ is $$-2^{1008}x$$. The option (B) is correct.

Answer (score 0):

$P(x)= 2(x^{2015}+ \binom{2015}{2}
 x^{2013}+\binom{2015}{4}x^{2011}+ \cdots \binom{2015}{2014}x)$

Using the remainder theorem, we have $P(i)$ as the remainder when $P(x)$ is divided by $x^2+1$.

Complete it from here. You may have to use some identity of binomial coefficients.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$(x-1)^2\equiv-2x\pmod{x^2+1}$$

$$(x-1)^3\equiv-2x(x-1)=2x-2x^2\equiv2x-(-2)$$

$$\implies(x-1)^4\equiv(-2x)^2\equiv-4$$

$$(x-1)^{4n+3}=((x-1)^4)^n(x-1)^3\equiv(-4)^n2(x+1)\equiv(-1)^n2^{2n+1}(x+1)$$

Similarly for $(x+1)^{4n+3}$

Here $4n+3=2015\iff n=?$

Comment: Please, can you expalin me **Why** $R(1)=0$ is not correct?

Comment: @Elementary You can only conclude from your work that $R(1)\equiv 0\pmod 2$.

Comment: @Wojowu I understood. Thank you!